# immutable structure values in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, structure, doubly-linked-list

Let's assume we have this structure:

```
typedef struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *prev;
}node;
```

and

```
typedef struct {
    node *front;
    node *rear;
}deque;
```

Since it is a doubly linked list, I would like to set `deque->front->next = NULL` and `deque->rear->prev = NULL` and I dont want these values to be changed no matter what the other functions do. Is such a thing possible in C ? And how would that be? 
Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking if sprinkling `const` in the right places would do the trick? Then the answer is "no".

Comment: `const` is a myth. Nothing is constant in `C`(except this)

Comment: @coderredoc: Well, literals (mostly) are.

Comment: @alk.: Even those are not dictated by standard - just the consequence that if you try to modify it, it is UB. Standard doesn't even ask for making it constant .

Comment: @Jens what I want to do is, I never change `deque->front->next` or `deque->rear->prev` directly. However, since it is a linked list, changes in other nodes MAY affect them too

Comment: @coderredoc: There is difference between `const` and "*constant*", isn't it? Regarding your statement about the the Standard, I agree.

Comment: @alk.: Yes there is a difference. `const` and constant are different. I admit you are right ( I swicthed between these two - but they are different)

Comment: Wild guess: maybe some sort of "write counter" could be added to test whether it's the first assignment (ok) or a subsequent one (denied).

Comment: "*I never change*" so you never add/remove something from the deque's head or tail?

Comment: "I would like to set deque->front->next = NULL and deque->rear->prev = NULL" - Why do you want this? How would you add the nodes to the list?

Comment: @sg7 I do add nodes to the list. I just dont add nodes to the previous of last or next of last, which would not make sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible in C. If a variable/field is not constant, it can be assigned anything.

It is possible to do that in C++ by defining a 'deque link' class and overloading its assignment function. Something like this:

```
class DequeLink {
    public:
        DequeLink& operator = (const DequeLink &dl) { /* check value and assign */ }
        DequeLink& operator = (void *p) { /* need this override to accept NULL as arg */ }

    private:
        DequeLink *m_pActualLink;
};

typedef struct {
    int data;
    DequeLink next;
    DequeLink prev;
} Node;
```

Comment: why the people insist in showing how things are done in C++ on plain C tagged questions?  Please, if you don't know C, don't flood.